# How can I check if an option is a flag with CLI11?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am using the CLI11 library ([link](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11)) for parsing of command line arguments of my programm.

Now I want to print information about the options of my program to stdout.
It seems that flags added via `App::add_flag(...)` are stored as Options internally as well, but I need to distinguish them in my output.

**How can I determine which option is a flag?**

Here is a simplified example:

```
std::string file, bool myflag;
CLI::App *command = app.add_subcommand("start", "Start the program");

command->add_option("file", file, "This is a file option")->required();
command->add_flag("--myflag", myflag);

print_description(command);
```

...

```
std::string print_description(CLI::App* command) {
    for (const auto &option : command->get_options()) {
      result << R"(<option name=")" << option->get_name() << R"(" description=")" << option->get_description()
             << R"(" type=")";
      if (/*option is a flag*/) {
        result << "flag";
      } else {
        result << "option";
      }
      result << R"("/>)";
    }
    return result.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue: https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11/issues/439, the function `Option::get_expected_min` will always return 0 for flags.
So it's possible to check it like this:

```cpp
if (option->get_expected_min() == 0) {
  result << "flag";
} else {
  result << "option";
}
```